# updateSearchResultsForSearchController JSON

Tags: json, swift, tableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I try to implement search to my tableview, I got the following error. 
How I am going to implement for JSON data?

```
var articleList: [JSON]? = []
var searchResults: [JSON]? = []
```

And my updateSearchResultsForSearchController function :

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.searchResults?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

    let array = (articleList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    searchResults = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

ERROR : '[JSON]?' is not convertible to 'NSArray'

Thanks...

Comment: make it (articleList! as NSArray)

Comment: this didnt work either...

Comment: try `articleList as! NSArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make (instead of cast) a new NSArray from your Swift array:

```
let nsArticleList = NSArray(array: articleList!)
```

Then use it:

```
let array = nsArticleList.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I got another error ;
                                                                                                            Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSArray' that accepts an argument list of type '(array: [JSON])'

Comment: I see. Although I'm not 100% sure, I think it's because of the `JSON` type inside your Swift array, it looks like `NSArray` doesn't know how to make an NS array from this Swift array of `JSON` type. I don't have a solution for this right now, unfortunately.